# How can I resize my window without losing to much image quality?

Tags: python, pygame, window

I want to make my window resizable without changing its aspect ratio. I tried using the `pygame.SCALED` flag, but the quality becomes horrible. Is there any way to make it resize smoothly like `transform.smoothresize`? If there isn't, is there any better way to resize my window without losing to much quality?

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload the image.
   adobe online tool for resizing images without losing quality

With most image resizing tools, you can drag and drop an image or upload it from your computer. Some tools even allow you to copy and paste an image.

2. Choose a resizing option.
   choosing image dimensions to resize images without losing quality

Some resizing tools allow you to choose from a list of preset resizing dimensions based on various social media platforms and common screen sizes. If you'd like, choose one of these presets from the menu.

If you'd rather set custom dimensions yourself, choose the Custom option and move on to the next step.

3. Type in the width and height dimensions.
   choosing image dimensions to resize an image without losing quality

Let’s say the image you want to resize is 6000 x 4000 pixels, and you want to resize it to 600 x 400 px to make it the featured image of your blog post. You simply have to type in those dimensions.

4. Download the resized image.
   resize-image-without-losing-quality-tutorial-4

Once the image has been resized, click Download. You can now download the image with its new dimensions and upload it to your website.

After completing the above steps, you may find that your image file size is still above 100KB. To get it even lower, we can turn to image compression.

Comment: I got the feeling that the question was more about playing at a different size rather than just getting a screen capture.